# jsTree with Json-Data, don't get metadata

Tags: json, jstree, oracle-apex

i read many suggestions concerning jsTree/Json/metadat, but I don't found a working solution. I want to get the metadata (e.g. id) if a node is clicked.

1st my Json Data:

```
[
  {
    "data":{
      "title":"TEST",
      "icon":"/i/small_folder.gif",
      "attr":{
        "id":"1000000000000000021"
      },
      "metadata":{
        "id":"1000000000000000021"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

2nd JS function which create the tree and should get the clicked id(ajax call and some oracle apex stuff)

```
function populateTree(pRegionId) {
  console.log('---Js Tree---');
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    async : true,
    url : 'wwv_flow.show',
    data : {
      "p_request" : 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_TREE',
      "p_flow_id" : $v('pFlowId'), // app id
      "p_flow_step_id" : $v('pFlowStepId'), // page id
      "p_instance" : $v('pInstance'), // session id

    },
    ggg : pRegionId,
    success : function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      var jsonobj = JSON.parse(data);
      apex.jQuery("#" + this.ggg).jstree({
       "themes" : {
          "theme" : "default",
          "dots" : false,
          "icons" : true
        },
        "json_data" : {
          "data" : [jsonobj]
        },
        "plugins" : ["themes","json_data", "ui"]
      //}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert(data.rslt.obj.data("jstree").id); });
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
          console.log(data);


        });

    }
  });
}
```

3rd the object where the id should be (firebug domview):

```
  args [a#1000000000000000301.jstree-clicked #, true, Object { originalEvent=Event click,  type=  "click",  timeStamp=30977664,  mehr...}]

inst  Object { data={...}, get_settings=function(), _get_settings=function(), mehr...}

rlbk false

rslt Object { obj={...}, e={...}}
  e Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=30977664, mehr...}  
  obj   jQuery(li.jstree-closed)
```

as you can see there is no id. So I guess something with the metadata part is messy but i cannt figure out where the mistake is.

Thanks in advance
Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I tracked my mistake down. If you can see in the json code from above:

```
[
  {
    "data":{
      "title":"TEST",
      "icon":"/i/small_folder.gif",
      "attr":{
        "id":"1000000000000000021"
      },
      "metadata":{
        "id":"1000000000000000021"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The metadataobject(?) is within the dataobject like the attr, all online validations show me that my jason code is valid. But the metadatas right place is after the data:

```
[
  {
    "data":{
      "title":"TEST",
      "icon":"/i/small_folder.gif",
      "attr":{
        "id":"1000000000000000021"
      }
    },
    "metadata":{
      "id":"1000000000000000021"
    }
  }
]
```

And now I get the id with the following js

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
          console.log(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));         
        });
```

And if you want an id within the li tag put an attr-object bevor the data-object like:

```
[
  {
    "attr":{
      "id":"1000000000000000021"
    },
    "data":{
      "title":"TEST",
      "icon":"/i/small_folder.gif",
      "attr":{
        "id":"1000000000000000021"
      }
    },
    "metadata":{
      "id":"1000000000000000021"
    }
  }
]
```

cu soon
mario

Comment: Hey @Mario, you can accept your own answer! This'll marked the question resolved, that'll help others who stumble on the question.

Comment: I keep getting 'undefined' for `.rslt`. It knows data is a function